# Erdős–Turan construction of Golomb ruler

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The following equation produces a [Golomb ruler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler) for every odd prime p

$$ 2pk + (k^2 \bmod p), \quad k\in[0,p-1] $$

and every two contiguous points has a unique difference.
my question is how to get k and k-1 if i know p and the difference between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given distance is congruent modulo $p$ to an odd number between $0$ and $2p$. This odd number is the difference between two successive squares. (Remember that the differences between successive perfect squares are exactly the odd numbers). The root of the larger of these two squares is the $k$ you seek.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i really don't get it, maybe an equation might help.

Comment: @user1748906 Which of the steps do you have trouble with?

Comment: how to get the two squares knowing d (the distance) ?

Comment: $(n+1)^2-n^2$ is $2n+1$, and if $2n+1=a$ then $n=\frac{a-1}{2}$. And $a$ must be the odd number between $0$ and $2p$ that equals $d$ modulo $p$.

Comment: i doesn't work i tried a = d mod p and it always even number ?!

Comment: @user1748906: No $a$ must be the _odd_ number between $0$ and $2p$ that equals $d$ modulo $p$. There is always such a number -- namely, there are exactly _two_ numbers in $[0,2p)$ that equal $d$ modulo $p$; one of them is even and the other is odd. You want the odd one.

Comment: look i tried golomb(5) and i get 0, 11, 24, 34, 41. suppose i picked 41 and 34 then d = 7, so a = d mod p => d = 7 mod 5 => d = 2  (even number) what iam doing wrong here

Comment: @user1748906: In your example $a=7$, because $7$ is the odd number between $0$ and $10$ that equals $7$ (modulo $5$). Therefore $n=\frac{7-1}{2}=3$, so your two elements are created by $n=3$ and $n=4$.

Comment: ok, but it does not work with 34 and 24 because a = 10

Comment: @user1748906: No, $a$ cannot be $10$ because $10$ is not an odd number. The odd number between $0$ and $10$ that is equal (modulo $5$) to $34-24$ is $5$. Since $a=5$ we get $n=\frac{5-1}{2}=2$, so these two elements are created by $n=2$ and $n=3$.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that I've written "equal to $d$ modulo $p$" all the time where I should have said "congruent to $d$, modulo $p$". Sorry if this slip-up confused you. I knew there was _something_ wrong with my phrasing...

Comment: never mind, it's not your fault that i suck at math.